# How to correctly log the signals of a long running function in node red? Getting heap-memory full error and file stays empty

Tags: heap-memory, node-red, file-writing

My Flow has following structure:
StartNode(InjectNode) -> LongRunningFunction(Custom) -> LogNode(File-Write set to Append)

StartNode: just a Inject node that I use to start the flow
LongRunningFunction: the function creates inside a longer for-loop a signal via
node.send(msg)

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5000000; i++){
    node.send({payload: i});
}
```

this is the full code of the LongRunningNode. Later I want to calculate some message string based on the counter inside the loop, but problem can be reproduced by above code

The file stays empty and the script stops execution after some time. If I connect a debug node as second output to LongRunningFunction the last console output is around  3236831, because the heap-memory is full

Is there a general problem with the structure of my program?

i even tried abusing context by putting

```
flow.set("pause", true);
while(flow.get("pause")){
}
```

into the for loop of enter code hereLongRunningFunction and setting "pause" to false again, when a file watch node triggers.
theoretically, this way it should send only 1 signal at a time and wait until the logging finished.

tldr: it never writes anything to the file and heap crashes

Edit: This may possibly be related to the problem:
https://nodejs.org/es/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/

the text is for node.js, so not sure how this is applies to node-red or how to fix it

Comment: Edit the question to include the full code in your function node and an image of your flow, because the nested XML is not a good description of what your flow is actually doing.

Comment: in simplified form the code is just for(let i = 0; i < 500000; i++){
    node.send({payload: i}, {payload: i});
} . file-write never seems to process the message

Comment: As I said, edit the question to include the full code and a proper image of your flow, what you have provided do far is not enough for anybody to help you

Comment: sry, but its literally just a for loop that continously is trying to send async msgs to a file-write node.the flow is just TriggerNode --> LongRunningFunction --> FileWriteNode. the debug node is hanging on the second output of LongRunningFunction, but isn't even relavant for the problem - I still get the same error if I leave it out.

Comment: I edited out the console node, because problem still persists when leaving it out and flow can be simplified to linear flow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach of a long running function is that is never yields back to the node.js event loop. That stalls all other activity in the runtime and nothing can make any progress.

The while loop approach is particularly bad; the *only* thing the runtime can do is sit in that while loop. **Nothing** else can happen outside of the while loop to change the context value you are testing.

There are lots of different ways to write long running functions using timers and callbacks that allow the node.js event loop to continue processing other events along side. It all depends on what you actually want to do in your flow.

Comment: but how do I block a node, so the other node can continue? I want the logging to happen right when the signals are sent, in the same order I send them in.